# How to hide material input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Normally if I want a form field to be included in the submission but not visible I do an `<input type="hidden" />`

However, `matInput` doesn't allow for a type of `hidden`. I could use a `display: none;` but that usually excludes the value from submission.

Is there a way to hide the input in a material dynamic form that also include the value in submission?

Comment: Do you want to be hidden or not to be clicked ?

Answer (score 13):

I did test it for Angular v11 where `hidden` is still not supported for `mat-form-field`, so instead of creating css class or use of `type=hidden` or `*ngIf` directive (sometimes you don't want to refresh component's lifecycle).

I just changed `[hidden]="variable"` -> `[class.cdk-visually-hidden]="variable"`.

Credit goes to @EdWood

Comment: This worked for me on Angular 12

Comment: Working on Angular 14

Comment: This is also working on Angular 15. I wonder why a 'simple' attribute as `hidden` is not supported on a `mat-form-field`.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned, type="hidden" does not work with matInput. If your open your browser console, you would see "ERROR Error: Input type "hidden" isn't supported by matInput." and if you tried to submit the form with type="hidden", then the form will be corrupt, only displaying part of the form values. A simple way of going around this issue is by using a CSS class on the mat-form-field tag:

```
<mat-form-field class="invisible example-full-width">
   <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi" ngModel name="fish">
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS snippet:

```
.invisible{
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In angular 10, you can use *ngIf with <mat-form-field>

Answer (score 4):

Use **hidden="true"** to solve this issue

```
<input  hidden="true"  matInput class="form-control" formControlName="yourfieldname">
```

Comment: This didnt work when I tried it

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: This solution works for Angular 7.

You can simply use **hidden** directive.

```
<mat-form-field [hidden]="!(formX.value.otherControl == '1')">
    <input matInput type="number" placeholder="An Input" formControlName="aControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

I have used a value in my form named formX (*formX.value.otherControl*) in my example but you can use **true** in your case.

```
<mat-form-field [hidden]="true">
    <input matInput type="number" placeholder="An Input" formControlName="aControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for ng10. Anyone know of another approach aside from using .css?

Comment: It doesn't work in Angular 10 for me as well. This works class="cdk-visually-hidden".

Answer (score 1):

since hidden fields are not visible , it does not material, you can alternatively define control in form in component as follow

```
this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        
        hidden_fld:["your_value",Validators.nullValidator],
        other_field: ['', Validators.required],
      
        });
```

so you are setting default value of hidden_fld, and on submit this value will also be send along with other form variables

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't found the answer. Here is how I got it successful given exactly what you wanted to do. Because I wanted to hide certain inputs, I just didn't include them in a  and the form got submitted successfully using action='' post='', and type='submit' button.
Example:

```
<form action='/path' method='post'>
     <mat-form-field class="form-element">
        <label for="item">
          <input matInput placeholder="My Item"
                 [value]="paymentDetail._amount" name="item" id="item">
        </label>
      </mat-form-field>
     <input name="anotherItem" id="anotherItem" type="hidden"
             [value]="model._itemDescription" >
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I have added a code for `matInput` you can see that at first `mat-form-field` is `input hidden` and works.
If you want to show be not to be clicked just you add `disabled` at the end of `input` and it will work.

`HTML`

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi" type="hidden">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9jxjd-huz6me?file=app/input-overview-example.html